# CSS: Is there a way to replicate background-size "cover" property just for a div inside another div?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have an image that follows the same behavior when you set in CSS `background-size:cover` but since in my case I can't use the image as background, I wonder if there is a way to have a div inside a div to behave the same?

Comment: can we use javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I feel dumb! duh, but it seems CSS can handle this with the new

**object-fit**
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp